# How to use java inner classes

Tags: java

I am new to java and in the learning stage. I am trying to make an app for android and was wondering how to use java inner classes

example : I have the following `test4.java` class in my android studio project

```
public class test4{   // outer class
   class getinfo{  // inner class
     public String getosname(){  // getosname function
       // something here
     }
  }
}
```

How can I call `getosname()` from outside the `test4` class and return the value which is inside the inner class `getinfo`?

Comment: Where do you want to call getosname? Inside or outside of test4?

Comment: yes i want to call getosname out side i mean an another java file which is Mainactivity.java

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Ok i edited question and removed second question so now can i get answer :(

Comment: For god sake, why do people learning Java, keep trying to program for Android?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call the `getosname()` method, you need an instance of the class `getinfo`. You create an instance of a class with the `new` operator. Since your class is an inner class, you'll first need an instance of the outer class:

```
test4 test4Instance = new test4();
test4.getinfo getinfoInstance = test4Instance.new getinfo();
getinfoInstance.getosname();
```

Now, use inner classes with caution. They're not very commonly used in Java because they solve very specific and rather rare problems. If you can, just make your `getinfo` a normal class inside its own getinfo.java file. In that case, you'll just need to do:

```
getinfo getinfoInstance = new getinfo();
getinfoInstance.getosname();
```

Answer (score 0):

Four type of inner classes
static inner class,
non static inner class,
local inner class,
anonymous inner class,

inner class access through only outer side class object.its provide access privilege for other classes